# Sqlite: convert a date to a day number in the month

Tags: sqlite, date

Here is my question: i've some date in my sqlite database. What I want to do is the following:

```
SELECT dates FROM Table1 WHERE dates > date('now','-1 month');
```

The result is:

```
2013-02-21 12:04:22
2013-02-28 12:04:22
2013-02-01 12:04:22
```

How can I convert those dates as the following:

```
2013-02-21 12:04:22 become 2 (day 2 of the month)
2013-02-28 12:04:22 become 9 (day 9 of the month)
2013-03-01 12:04:22 become 10(day 10 of the month)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where do these numbers 2,9,10 come from? I see no connection with the dates.

Comment: Now (20/03/2013) - 1 month ==> 20/02/2013
On this period (from 20/02/2013 to 20/03/2013) 2013-02-21 corresponds of the second day on this period (day 2), 2013-02-28 corresponds of the 9th day on this period,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
select julianday(dates) - julianday(date('now','-1 month')) + 1
from table1
where dates > date('now','-1 month')
```

Comment: With this, the first date (2013-02-21 12:04:22) become 2,50303 ! Almost perfect :) how can I keep only the integer part (keep 2 and drop the 0,50303)?

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast((julianday(dates) - julianday(date('now','-1 month')) + 1)as int)
from table1
where dates > date('now','-1 month')
```

to keep only the integer part :) thanks a lot to AnatolyS